# how to slice two images into one image in iphone

Tags: iphone

I have one app where i need to slice two or three images into one image can anybody help me in this

Comment: How you gonna slice two or three images into one? Or do you mean slice one image into two or three? But you need code that can do this or what? please be more specific

Comment: ya i want to slice 3 different images and put them into one imageview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U want 3 diff images in one imageview for that u
create 1 UIview and 3 UIImageview through CGRect u specify the position of the images and finally u simply add all imageviews in the view.